# Blender Python Axis swapping on PoseBone

Tags: python, animation, bones

I am writing an export script to export a custom animation format. I need to export a bone's location, rotation, and scale, and easily obtained the location and scale information with no problems. But trying to get the rotation data, the Axis flip at the first and last frame, but they still animate fine in blender itself. This dose not matter if I use a script or just the python console in blender, regardless of rotation system. I am accessing the rotation via

```
Primary = bpy.context.active_object.parent.pose.bones['Primary']
loc, rot, scale = Primary.matrix.decompose()
rot = rot.to_euler()
```

Here is my blend file that shows this behavior. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37681 and yes this script is for a Minecraft mod. The bone named "Primary" is the one in this file that exhibits this behavior. It will be used to track a Minecraft item to an animated rig.

Comment: Didn't manage to recreate your issue with a simple test scene (link at the end). Upload your blend file and people might be able to find your issue (I suspect it's caused by something in your specific animation). http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37651

Comment: Did you look into [Euler.make_compatible()](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/mathutils.html#mathutils.Euler.make_compatible) to stop it from flipping?

Comment: @CoDEmaxX I tried this and initially thought it worked, and then the flipping returned on another animation test. maybe its something with my .blend or something.